# NullPointerException when creating an array from a file- Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am getting a nullpointerexception when I create a large array from a file.  A new element is to be created for each line of the .txt file.  I get the nullPointerException when I use the array created from this file.

Here is my code:

```
static String[] results=new String[172820];
            public String[] getWords(){
    try{
        InputStream fstream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.enable1);

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        for (int x=0; (strLine = br.readLine()) != null; x++)   {
           results[x]=strLine;            
        }
        in.close();
       }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
           System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
       return results;
}
```

Comment: You should use Step Over of the debugger to locate which line of code throws this exception.

Comment: Or use `adb logcat` within a command prompt.

Comment: `static String[] results = new String[172820];` @.@ Don't do this. Use an ArrayList, you won't have to worry about out of bounds exceptions, or allocating more than you need.

Comment: Do you believe that this is the most efficient way of instantiating a 172820 array?  Will the device lag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I was going to mention that most devices have a maximum heap size of 16MB and that you might be exceeding that, but then I found [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/be86695ff25c742c/25c8c8f1a387a465). It would appear that 512 is the maximum array size. I would try the suggestion given by @kcoppock, and try an ArrayList.

As a side note: it would seem you're loading "words" into an array. No device on the market is anywhere near fast enough to iterate over a 172K item array with any efficiency; I believe you're setting the user up for a slow and painful experience.